# Ajustar ancho y alto de celda de excell con c#

Tags: c#, excel, objeto, int

Hola chicos tengo un problema, estoy utilizando **e-pluss en c#** para manipular una hoja de cálculo y resulta que tengo un texto no se me acomoda a mi celda
por ejemplo:

```
hoja.Cells["A16].Style.WrapText=true
```

Para ajustar el contenido de la celda, luego aplique un rango de celdas

```
hoja.Cells[" A16:K16"].Merge=true;
```

Sin embargo solamente me unió las celdas pero el resto de contenido que sobrepasaba ese rango quedó oculto

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias lo tamare en cuenta para futuras  preguntas

Comment: WrapText ajusta el texto y el tamaño de la celda **siempre y cuando** no se haya alterado el alto de fila original bajo ningún concepto. Y aun así, si es mucho texto, no lo ajusta bien porque no le cabe. Si has alterado en algún momento el alto original, tienes que modificarlo tú para que se vaya ajustando hasta que todo el texto se quede visible.